# How to accept only alphabets without space in regexed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I want to validate full name in contact form. I want to restrict spaces in alphabets. textbox should only accept a-z characters.

I used this regular expression

```
ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z ]*$"
```

But it allows spaces also.

Comment: It accepts because your expression contains space in it. Change it to `ValidationExpression="^[a-z]*$"`

Comment: how to restrict textbox of 50 alphabets with this validation [a-zA-Z]*$ @nu11p01n73R

Comment: You can use quantifiers for that. I have edited my answer to include that.  Hope it helps you now

Comment: hai friend i need one more regular expression which should accept alphabets a-z and numerics 1-9 . can u once more help me @nu11p01n73R

Comment: just add `1-9` to the character sequance. `ValidationExpression="^[a-z1-9]*$"`

Comment: Are you sure you are talking about a contact name? These wouldn't pass:  "안현수" "Виктор Ан" "Ahn Hyun-Soo" "J. R. Celski" "François-Louis Tremblay" "አበበ ቢቂላ" …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because it contains spaces in the character squance.

You can specify the pattern correctly as

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-z]*$"
```

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `[a-z]*` Matches zero or more characters
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/jJ3yT5/1)

**EDIT**

To restrict the characters to `50` we could use a quantifier as

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-z]{,50}$"
```

- `{,50}` Quantifier ensures that there can be a maximum of 50 characters.

Comment: If the requirement is that its not case sensitive than either do a-zA-Z or use the regex modifier

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the space inside your character class?

Also anchor the regex so that it matches at the start of a line :

^[a-zA-Z]*$

And take into consideration that ^ and $ can be influenced by the modifier that says it should match at a newline or not

Answer (score 1):

I would just use "^[a-zA-Z]+$".

I think the issue you have is there is a space between the Z and ]. When I tested this it allowed spaces into the regular expression. I also changed the * to + to not allow a blank string.